# Limiting view of groups/persons and higher level site URL link

Tags: sharepoint-online

We are creating subsites for team partners. I do not want them to be able to "uplink" or click on the "more" link to see all/other groups or users outside their subsite page.

Answer (score 1):

If your partners are external users, then limit all site and web permission to read access for "Everyone except external users" instead of everyone". Create a group for your partner and break inherited permission on the partner sub site. Add contribute permission level to the partner group on the sub site.

Edit all groups settings to disallow non members to see members of group. This won't stop users from seeing other groups, but they can't see members. If you need to hide partner names from each other, use non descriptive group names and make sure to document which group use which partner sub site.

[image]